# How to change the color in a specific range of text in InputText

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have a problem and I've hunted for it and so far nothing ...

I need to change the color of a text in textInput, for example, I'm typing and part of my text would have to be of a different color, I basically wanted to apply more than one style at different intervals using TextInput

I use the TextInput own onSelectionChange method to retrieve the start and end intervals, is there a possibility to change the text from an interval?

I don't know if I managed to be clear in any way, but I'm here for you if you need more information, I'll be grateful if you help me

Here is an image with the example more or less than I need.

Thank you.

[Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvzhH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Soooo there are a couple of ways to achieve the desired effect you are describing above, but which one you use is a bit dependent on your use case. For the example you have above, they are likely using a function to split the input based upon the position of the @ symbol in the text string, and wrapping one or both of the split strings in span tags to target the text with specific styling.

```js
var initial = 'example@somedomain.com';
console.log("Initial String : " + initial);

var splitStrings = initial.split("@");
console.log(splitStrings[0], "@" + splitStrings[1]);
```

When using split in this way though, make sure to re-add the character used to split the initial string. If you are trying to split based on the index, then slice based on the index of the string character to start the new styling would be the best option, and if it is consistent from that point forward you can omit the endIndex value from the call to dynamically select the rest of the string.

```js
var initial = "string of a certain character length"
console.log(initial);


var firstHalf = initial.slice(0, 5);
var secondHalf = initial.slice(5);
console.log(firstHalf + secondHalf);
```

Once you have the split string values how you need them, then it is just a matter of wrapping the correct values with tags to target using CSS. Super rough example using basic HTML, JS and inline style below.

```js
function display() {
  var initial = document.getElementById("initial").value;
  var first = initial.slice(0,2)
  var second = initial.slice(2)
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = first + '<span style="color:blue">' + second + '</span>'
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
<input type="text" id="initial">
<button onClick="display();">display</button>
```